# Testing a Spring class that extends AbstractPdfView

Tags: java, spring, testing, pdf, junit

I am in the process of writing jUnit tests for my application and I am wondering how I can test the following class:

```
public class PdfBottomCheckView extends AbstractPdfView {

    @Override
    protected void buildPdfDocument(Map<String, Object> model, Document document, PdfWriter writer, 
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        MyObjet1 object1 = (MyObject1) model.get("object1");
        MyObject2 object2= (MyObject2) model.get("object2");

        HelperClass helper= new HelpClass(getMessageSourceAccessor(), getServletContext());

        helper.writeLogo(document);
        helper.writeFooter(document, writer);

        document.add(help.generateOutput(object1, object2, 105, new int[]{55,20,30}, helper.getNormalFont()));      }
}
```

There is a complete example of how I implemented this with spring [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-export-data-to-pdf-file-via-abstractpdfview/)

I found another website that shows you can compare byte[] to test pdf output.  That article is [here](http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/30067/1954?pf=true)  (Scroll down to the heading 'Producing the Correct Binary Output')

I am getting an error running the test on the helper line.  How can I mock or pass valid values for the Helper Class?  I am using Spring 3.0.5, jUnit 4, and Mockito 1.8.5.

Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationObjectSupport instance [com.test.PdfBottomCheckView: unnamed] does not run in an ApplicationContext

Answer (score 0):

Create a factory class that produces helpers.  Pass the factory class in as a constructor arg for your PdfBottomCheckView.  Them mock your factory in your test and from there you can generate a mock helper class.

If you aren't using Mockito use that.